# Helps with wordpress nav menu

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I need help to let working the js-scroll-trigger into wp_nav_menu.

Orginial code is:

```
<ul class="navbar-nav text-uppercase ml-auto">
                     <li class="nav-item">
                         <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#collection">ByLex Collection</a>
                     </li>
                     <li class="nav-item">
                         <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#customs">Custom Wigs</a>
                     </li>
                     <li class="nav-item">
                         <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#book">Book A service</a>
                     </li>
                     <li class="nav-item">
                         <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#shop">Shop</a>
                     </li>
                     <li class="nav-item">
                         <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#about">About</a>
                     </li>
                     <li class="nav-item">
                         <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#contact">Contact</a>
                     </li>
                 </ul>
```

I insert this into functions.php ->

```
// Menu Support
 add_theme_support('menus');



// Register Menus
register_nav_menus(
    
     array(

         'top-menu' => __('Top Menu', 'theme'),
     )
 )
```

then,
into header.php ->

wp_nav_menu(

```
         array(

             'theme_location' => 'top_menu',
             'menu' => 'main-menu',
             'menu_class' => 'navbar-nav text-uppercase ml-auto'
             'container' => 'ul',
             'container_class' =>'navbar-nav text-uppercase ml-auto',
             'add_a_class' => 'nav-link js-scroll-trigger';

                                            
         ));            
    ?>
```

I tried different methods but i can't call the class without have an error with the rest of the code...
Someone knows what I should modify to running the javascript class working?

Many thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please: 1) format your code appropriately 2) Clarify what error are you getting and what do you execute to get this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`add_a_class` isn't valid arg for `wp_nav_menu`

Try this in your **functions.php**

```
add_filter( 'nav_menu_css_class', 'add_my_class_to_nav_menu', 10, 2 );
function add_my_class_to_nav_menu( $classes, $item ){
    $classes[] = 'nav-item';
    return $classes;
}

add_filter( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', 'add_link_atts');
function add_link_atts($atts) {
  $atts['class'] = 'nav-link js-scroll-trigger';
  return $atts;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
It's reading the 'nav-link' from bootstrap but do not read the 'js-scroll-trigger' from the javascript..

Comment: can you provide html result of your code?

Comment: I can see it from the "inspection" code.

do have any  platform where we can talk directly please?

Comment: Edit question with entire UL HTML tag. Like in your first sample, but with real result.

Comment: <ul id=menu-main-menu" class"navbar-nav text-uppercase ml-auto">
<li id="menu-item-27" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-27 nav-link js-scroll-trigger">
<a href="#">#</a>
</li>
</ul>

LIKE THAT?

Comment: Is not  reading the script and also some css from the anchor tag..
My html code it was ->
<ul class="navbar-nav text-uppercase ml-auto">
<li class="nav-item">
<a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#"># Collection</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
<a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#">#</a>
</li>
</ul>

Comment: i need to insert the 'nav-link' and 'js-scroll-trigger' for the anchor tag and the 'nav-item' for <li>

Comment: Thank you now is working
But it doesn't work the selector as I build outside wordpress

Comment: Do you have the explanation of the code in the documentation please?
Maybe on wordpress documentation...

Comment: What do you mean in outside wordpress

Comment: Google nav_menu_css_class and nav_menu_link_attributes for documentation

Comment: I build the theme with html/css/javascript and now I upload everything on wordpress
from landing page to e-commerce

Comment: If your html code is right then maybe your JavaScript is missing

Comment: no because its fully working outside wordpres..thanks by the way

Comment: but i can running modify the wp_custom.css
the issue was with the classes.
thank you
there is a chance if i need some other advice ask about it with some instant messaging please?
Many thanks!

Comment: the nav-link.active

Comment: U Legend!
Fix it and everything is running!
Top!
I really would like to understand how's it works if is possible please..

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm just confused about the classes for different elements. Everything works based on 2 WordPress hooks, one for the LI element and the other for the internal link. You can use the search to access the documentation and study these hooks in more detail, their possibilities are wider, for example, you can apply classes not to all LI elements, and you can also change not only the classes of internal links.

Comment: thank you nikita, you helped me a lot not  a worries
need to study and understand better wordpress indentation, if you have any documentation where i can read about and learn more it will be a pleasure if you  link up.
you sorted me the issue.thank you!!!

Comment: You are welcome! Mark answer as accepted please.